# Commons FileUpload. Empty Items list

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons

I use apache commons file-upload to upload files on servlet. But after parsing request I always get empty list of file items. My code looks like this:

```
if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Expected `multipart/...` content-type header ");
}

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

logger.debug("Items size: " + items.size());
```

Where can be problem? Request sent correctly

Answer (score 0):

Add  enctype="multipart/form-data"  in your form action

```
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
                          enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

 </form>



 DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
 // maximum size that will be stored in memory
 factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
 // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
 factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

 // Create a new file upload handler
 ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
 // maximum file size to be uploaded.
 upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

 try{ 
         // Parse the request to get file items.
         List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

 }catch(Exception e){

 }
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Comment: Request contains content-type you mention. If it don't, then I always get error `UnsupportedOperationException("Expected `multipart/..`

Answer (score 0):

When creating the DiskFileItemDirectory use this this constructor

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(FILE_SIZE, new File("/yourfolder"));
```

The FILE_SIZE is max file size you allow to upload. Make sure you have **permissions** to the folder location at "/yourfolder" (change this ...)